# Suppress "Expected '===' and instead saw '=='." error in jslint

Tags: javascript, debugging, jslint

How can I stop the error message `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.` from appearing in jslint. 
Doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: I read the instructions, it seems it is not possible, along with many other features such as if blocks. You can still write JavaScript without `==`.

Comment: It seems to be (almost always) a harmless error. Have you seen [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fnja3/1/)

Comment: Use [jshint](http://jshint.com/) which allows you to turn `===` off.

Comment: @Ming-Tang what if i really need to use `==` when say i am comparing a `number` with a `string`

Answer (score 41):

For those using JSHint, you can turn off this warning by setting the option **eqeqeq** to false in your JSHint options (usually **.jshintrc**)

```
"eqeqeq": false
```

From the documentation: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#eqeqeq

Edit:

If you want to be a good citizen and fix your code to use the recommended comparison instead of turning the warning off, make sure both sides of the comparison are using the same type.

For example:

```
"123" == 123          // true, I'm lazy and JSHint hates me
"123" === 123         // false, no love
Number("123") === 123 // true, no warning
```

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty hot off the press.

Douglas Crockford has just added an 'eqeq' option to the JSLint tool.

See one of the June 12, 2011 edits on GitHub:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commits/2e8d430b5b9543caefb3743513181f1295f52ddf/jslint.js

Ad the time of writing it hadn't been updated on the JSLint front page, but i've tested it with the following and get no `==` related warnings:

```
/*jslint eqeq: true*/
var x = 0;
if (x == 1) {
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Works for me but has to be placed just above the statement.

Comment: As stated by @iLoveUnicorns works great just above the statement. Too bad I could not put that line in my .jshintrc. Besides, I did not find any documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

Although its late its worth, it would help some one who is in need

To disable use -

```
/* eslint eqeqeq: 0 */
```

To make it as warning use -

```
/* eslint eqeqeq: 1 */
```

Comment: Worked! I got this error from within Visual Studio: `eqeqeq (ESlint) Expected '!==' and instead saw'='` and this fix worked like charm!

Comment: As a note, this goes at the top of the .js file you want to suppress.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that there is no option for that. The only way is to either use `===` or modify the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint). I almost always use `===` anyway. It's better in general unless you know that `==` is *really* what you want.

Comment: except when comparing to null: `some == null` returns `true` if `some === undefined` or `some === null`, wich may be usefull.

Comment: Sas just about to say the same as @Koolinc. `== null` is the only valid use case for `==` . There are plenty of use cases for `if(value)` without the check.

Comment: @Koolinc Yes, there are cases where it's useful, but I use `===` by default.

Comment: @Raynos: Why the hate for `==`? If you know what you're doing, there's no problem with using it. JSLint not providing an option to turn that warning off is taking opinionatedness a step too far.

Comment: @Tim I agree there's no problem if you know it's what you want, and it would be nice if JSLint had that option. When I've used JSLint (I don't normally), I just ignored the warnings when I knew I had a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

same error show me I can fix by using this way

```
status.user_profile.toString() === props.props.id.toString()
```

I'm using react js give example I'm using something like that

```
id = 1
```

if I excess params show me like this

```
params :{ id:"1" }
```

If I excess this way

```
id == params.id // output true
```

If I excess this way

```
id === params.id // output false
```

because not 100% eqality so show me error in terminal

```
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='
```

So I can think about and fix it by converting same data type like this

```
id.toString()  === params.id.toString()  // return true
```

Comment: While this answer works, it really does not scale well and I dont see the point of the warning especially with most use cases as most database ids are integers (which may be a number or a string) it helps to loosely check them